# jquery dialog submit button event

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, jquery-ui

I have a jquery dialog, what I want is by the 'submit' button to call a WCF method. But it seems to be not working.

Code piece 1:

```
       $("#generatePinsDialog").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          width: 400,
          buttons: [
              { text: 'Submit', click: GeneratePINs }
           ]});
```

Code piece 2:

```
    function GeneratePINs()
    {
        var x= 0; y= 0;
        var c = $("#newInmateCount").val(); // get a value from a textbox
        var e = $("selected",this).val();  // get a value from a drop down menu
        if (e == 0) {
            y= 1;
        }
        else {
            x= 1
        }

      $.getJSON('/iServices/iService.svc/' + c + '/' + y+ '/' + x, function (response) {
    });
    $(this).dialog('close'); // Close it
```

}

In my WCF method code, I set a breakpoint. However it had not been reached at all.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You are missing an `'` after `iService.svc/` . Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(this).dialog('close')` to `$("#generatePinsDialog").dialog('close')`

I don't believe the dialog context usually gets passed when using a named function

Comment: I tried it and comment out all code except close part. It doesn't close.

Comment: Did you add a console.log or alert() to see if GeneratePINs is being called?

Comment: I added alert("Hello world") then it is called.

Comment: I've made a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/szR2A/3/) that shows the dialog closing in an external function.

Comment: Have you try '$(this)'? Maybe something else wrong in the code, Iam investgating it.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/szR2A/4/) is an example with `$(this).dialog('close')` Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your .svc request is formed properly?  Try pasting the .svc url into the browser to make sure that you're forming the url correctly.  Also, make sure your .svc is set up properly to allow a GET and not just POST if you're using $.getJSON

Comment: I used   [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "myurl blah blah", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]